# Dependent clause/ prepositional phrase in second clause with comma

Tags: commas

Am I right in punctuating the sentence this way?

Joe and Jim walked down the street, and, at the corner, Joe found a nickel.

This is just an example. More importantly, I need to know in general case scenarios. Also, does this apply to an 'if clause' starting the second part of the sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, style books recommend a comma to separate two complete/independent sentences joined by a coördinate conjunction like *and* and *or*. So the first comma is good. The commas around *at the corner*, however, are often not necessary. In this case I'd leave them out, but I wouldn't say they are wrong.

> Joe and Jim walked down the street, and at the corner Joe found a nickel.

Subordinate conjunctions, like *if* and *because*, are often separated from the main clause by a comma. But, when it is closely connected to the main clause, such as when the main clause is felt to be incomplete without it, the subordinate clause usually doesn't have a comma. This is less common than defining/restricting relative clauses, which have the same lack of a comma, but somewhat similar.

Comment: Not to mention the obvious alternative: "Joe and Jim walked down the street, and Joe found a nickel at the corner." You can typically reorganize the sentence if too many commas are getting smashed into it.

Comment: @MrHen: Quite so.